# Fiware-Device-Simulator Orion can handle bool type vale?

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm trying to use the fiware device simulator in orion to generate some entities, but in my entities I have some properties with type boolean. For example:

```
staticAttributes": 
          [
          {
              "name": "active",
              "type": "boolean",
              "value": true,
              "metadata": [ ]
          }]
```

When I execute the simulator the entity is created in orion but when I find this entity the bool value y translated to string value:

```
{
        "id": "XXXX.xxxx.001",
        "type": "XXXX.xxxx",
        "active": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "value": "true",
            "metadata": {}
        }
```

Somebody knows how I can handle bool type in fiware-device-simulator orion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fiware config file have to be set to use NGSI v2. The version 1 parse all the type to a string